# Hsqldb transaction log rollback cause

Tags: transaction-log, hsqldb

I'm fairly new to the database world but I had to use an `hsqldb-2.0.0` database for a netflow collector software. As the software shows no output even if the client is collecting the flows I investigated the database and it seems that after committing some changes it rolls back to the previous state (the empty one). This is the sql log :

```
2016-03-07 09:30:51.217 0 SET DATABASE TRANSACTION CONTROL LOCKS 
2016-03-07 09:30:51.217 0 COMMIT 
2016-03-07 09:30:51.217 0 SET DATABASE DEFAULT ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED 
2016-03-07 09:30:51.217 0 COMMIT 
2016-03-07 09:30:51.217 0 SET DATABASE TRANSACTION ROLLBACK ON CONFLICT TRUE 
2016-03-07 09:30:51.217 0 COMMIT 
2016-03-07 09:30:51.217 0 SET DATABASE TEXT TABLE DEFAULTS '' 
2016-03-07 09:30:51.217 0 COMMIT 
2016-03-07 09:30:51.217 0 SET DATABASE SQL NAMES FALSE 
2016-03-07 09:30:51.217 0 COMMIT 
2016-03-07 09:30:51.217 0 SET DATABASE SQL REFERENCES FALSE 
2016-03-07 09:30:51.217 0 COMMIT 
2016-03-07 09:30:51.217 0 SET DATABASE SQL SIZE TRUE 
2016-03-07 09:30:51.217 0 COMMIT 
2016-03-07 09:30:51.217 0 SET DATABASE SQL TYPES FALSE 
2016-03-07 09:30:51.217 0 COMMIT 
2016-03-07 09:30:51.217 0 SET DATABASE SQL TDC DELETE TRUE 
2016-03-07 09:30:51.217 0 COMMIT 
2016-03-07 09:30:51.217 0 SET DATABASE SQL TDC UPDATE TRUE 
2016-03-07 09:30:51.217 0 COMMIT 
2016-03-07 09:30:51.217 0 SET DATABASE SQL TRANSLATE TTI TYPES TRUE 
2016-03-07 09:30:51.217 0 COMMIT 
2016-03-07 09:30:51.217 0 SET DATABASE SQL CONCAT NULLS TRUE 
2016-03-07 09:30:51.217 0 COMMIT 
2016-03-07 09:30:51.217 0 SET DATABASE SQL UNIQUE NULLS TRUE 
2016-03-07 09:30:51.217 0 COMMIT 
2016-03-07 09:30:51.217 0 SET DATABASE SQL CONVERT TRUNCATE TRUE 
2016-03-07 09:30:51.217 0 COMMIT 
2016-03-07 09:30:51.217 0 SET DATABASE SQL AVG SCALE 0 
2016-03-07 09:30:51.217 0 COMMIT 
2016-03-07 09:30:51.217 0 SET DATABASE SQL DOUBLE NAN TRUE 
2016-03-07 09:30:51.217 0 COMMIT 
2016-03-07 09:30:51.217 0 SET FILES WRITE DELAY 500 MILLIS 
2016-03-07 09:30:51.217 0 SET FILES BACKUP INCREMENT TRUE 
2016-03-07 09:30:51.217 0 COMMIT 
2016-03-07 09:30:51.217 0 SET FILES CACHE SIZE 10000 
2016-03-07 09:30:51.217 0 COMMIT 
2016-03-07 09:30:51.217 0 SET FILES CACHE ROWS 50000 
2016-03-07 09:30:51.217 0 COMMIT 
2016-03-07 09:30:51.217 0 SET FILES SCALE 32 
2016-03-07 09:30:51.217 0 COMMIT 
2016-03-07 09:30:51.217 0 SET FILES LOB SCALE 32 
2016-03-07 09:30:51.217 0 COMMIT 
2016-03-07 09:30:51.217 0 SET FILES DEFRAG 0 
2016-03-07 09:30:51.217 0 COMMIT 
2016-03-07 09:30:51.217 0 SET FILES NIO TRUE 
2016-03-07 09:30:51.217 0 COMMIT 
2016-03-07 09:30:51.217 0 SET FILES NIO SIZE 256 
2016-03-07 09:30:51.217 0 COMMIT 
2016-03-07 09:30:51.217 0 SET FILES LOG TRUE 
2016-03-07 09:30:51.217 0 COMMIT 
2016-03-07 09:30:51.217 0 SET FILES LOG SIZE 50 
2016-03-07 09:30:51.217 0 COMMIT 
2016-03-07 09:30:51.217 0 CREATE USER SA PASSWORD DIGEST 'd41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e' 
2016-03-07 09:30:51.217 0 COMMIT 
2016-03-07 09:30:51.217 0 ALTER USER SA SET LOCAL TRUE 
2016-03-07 09:30:51.217 0 CREATE SCHEMA PUBLIC AUTHORIZATION DBA 
2016-03-07 09:30:51.217 0 COMMIT 
2016-03-07 09:30:51.217 0 ALTER SEQUENCE SYSTEM_LOBS.LOB_ID RESTART WITH 1 
2016-03-07 09:30:51.217 0 COMMIT 
2016-03-07 09:30:51.217 0 SET DATABASE DEFAULT INITIAL SCHEMA PUBLIC 
2016-03-07 09:30:51.217 0 COMMIT 
2016-03-07 09:30:51.217 0 GRANT USAGE ON DOMAIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SQL_IDENTIFIER TO PUBLIC 
2016-03-07 09:30:51.217 0 COMMIT 
2016-03-07 09:30:51.217 0 GRANT USAGE ON DOMAIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.YES_OR_NO TO PUBLIC 
2016-03-07 09:30:51.217 0 COMMIT 
2016-03-07 09:30:51.217 0 GRANT USAGE ON DOMAIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TIME_STAMP TO PUBLIC 
2016-03-07 09:30:51.217 0 COMMIT 
2016-03-07 09:30:51.217 0 GRANT USAGE ON DOMAIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CARDINAL_NUMBER TO PUBLIC 
2016-03-07 09:30:51.217 0 COMMIT 
2016-03-07 09:30:51.217 0 GRANT USAGE ON DOMAIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CHARACTER_DATA TO PUBLIC 
2016-03-07 09:30:51.217 0 COMMIT 
2016-03-07 09:30:51.217 0 GRANT DBA TO SA 
2016-03-07 09:30:51.217 0 COMMIT 
2016-03-07 09:30:51.232 2 COMMIT 
2016-03-07 09:30:51.232 2 ROLLBACK 
2016-03-07 09:30:57.207 3 CREATE TABLE IpSegments ( IpSeg VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,SegName VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL) 
2016-03-07 09:30:57.207 3 COMMIT 
2016-03-07 09:30:57.223 3 CREATE TABLE Raw_V1 ( RouterIP VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL, SysUptime BIGINT, Secs BIGINT, Nsecs BIGINT, SrcAddr VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL, DstAddr VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL, NextHop VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL, Input INT NOT NULL, Output INT NOT NULL, dPkts BIGINT, dOctets BIGINT, aFirst BIGINT, aLast BIGINT, SrcPort INT NOT NULL, DstPort INT NOT NULL, Prot INT NOT NULL, TOS INT NOT NULL, Flags INT, Stamp VARCHAR(15) NULL ) 
2016-03-07 09:30:57.223 3 COMMIT 
2016-03-07 09:30:57.238 3 CREATE TABLE Raw_V5 ( RouterIP VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL, SysUptime BIGINT, Secs BIGINT, Nsecs BIGINT, Flow_Sequence BIGINT NOT NULL, Engine_Type INT NOT NULL, Engine_ID INT NOT NULL, SrcAddr VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL, DstAddr VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL, NextHop VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL, Input INT NOT NULL, Output INT NOT NULL, dPkts BIGINT, dOctets BIGINT, aFirst BIGINT, aLast BIGINT, SrcPort INT NOT NULL, DstPort INT NOT NULL, Tcp_Flags INT NOT NULL, Prot INT NOT NULL, TOS INT NOT NULL, Src_As INT NOT NULL, Dst_As INT NOT NULL, Src_Mask INT NOT NULL, Dst_Mask INT NOT NULL, Stamp VARCHAR(15) NULL ) 
2016-03-07 09:30:57.238 3 COMMIT 
2016-03-07 09:30:57.238 3 CREATE TABLE Raw_V7 ( RouterIP VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL, SysUptime BIGINT, Secs BIGINT, Nsecs BIGINT, Flow_Sequence BIGINT NOT NULL, SrcAddr VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL, DstAddr VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL, NextHop VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL, Input INT NOT NULL, Output INT NOT NULL, dPkts BIGINT, dOctets BIGINT, aFirst BIGINT, aLast BIGINT, SrcPort INT NOT NULL, DstPort INT NOT NULL, Flags INT NOT NULL, Tcp_Flags INT NOT NULL, Prot INT NOT NULL, TOS INT NOT NULL, Src_As INT NOT NULL, Dst_As INT NOT NULL, Src_Mask INT NOT NULL, Dst_Mask INT NOT NULL, Flags1 INT NOT NULL, Router_Sc VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL, Stamp VARCHAR(15) NULL ) 
2016-03-07 09:30:57.238 3 COMMIT 
2016-03-07 09:30:57.238 3 CREATE TABLE Raw_V8_AS ( RouterIP VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL, SysUptime BIGINT, Secs BIGINT, Nsecs BIGINT, Flow_Sequence BIGINT NOT NULL, Engine_Type CHAR(1) NOT NULL, Engine_ID CHAR(1) NOT NULL, Flows BIGINT NOT NULL, dPkts BIGINT NOT NULL, dOctets BIGINT NOT NULL, aFirst BIGINT NOT NULL, aLast BIGINT NOT NULL, Src_As INT NOT NULL, Dst_As INT NOT NULL, Input INT NOT NULL, Output INT NOT NULL, Stamp VARCHAR(15) NULL ) 
2016-03-07 09:30:57.238 3 COMMIT 
2016-03-07 09:30:57.254 3 CREATE TABLE Raw_V8_ProtoPort ( RouterIP VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL, SysUptime BIGINT, Secs BIGINT, Nsecs BIGINT, Flow_Sequence BIGINT NOT NULL, Engine_Type CHAR(1) NOT NULL, Engine_ID CHAR(1) NOT NULL, Flows BIGINT NOT NULL, dPkts BIGINT NOT NULL, dOctets BIGINT NOT NULL, aFirst BIGINT NOT NULL, aLast BIGINT NOT NULL, Prot INT NOT NULL, SrcPort INT NOT NULL, DstPort INT NOT NULL, Stamp VARCHAR(15) NULL ) 
2016-03-07 09:30:57.254 3 COMMIT 
2016-03-07 09:30:57.254 3 CREATE TABLE Raw_V8_DstPrefix ( RouterIP VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL, SysUptime BIGINT, Secs BIGINT, Nsecs BIGINT, Flow_Sequence BIGINT NOT NULL, Engine_Type CHAR(1) NOT NULL, Engine_ID CHAR(1) NOT NULL, Flows BIGINT NOT NULL, dPkts BIGINT NOT NULL, dOctets BIGINT NOT NULL, aFirst BIGINT NOT NULL, aLast BIGINT NOT NULL, Dst_Prefix VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL, Dst_Mask INT NOT NULL, Dst_As INT NOT NULL, Output INT NOT NULL, Stamp VARCHAR(15) NULL ) 
2016-03-07 09:30:57.254 3 COMMIT 
2016-03-07 09:30:57.254 3 CREATE TABLE Raw_V8_SrcPrefix ( RouterIP VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL, SysUptime BIGINT, Secs BIGINT, Nsecs BIGINT, Flow_Sequence BIGINT NOT NULL, Engine_Type CHAR(1) NOT NULL, Engine_ID CHAR(1) NOT NULL, Flows BIGINT NOT NULL, dPkts BIGINT NOT NULL, dOctets BIGINT NOT NULL, aFirst BIGINT NOT NULL, aLast BIGINT NOT NULL, Src_Prefix VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL, Src_Mask INT NOT NULL, Src_As INT NOT NULL, Input INT NOT NULL, Stamp VARCHAR(15) NULL ) 
2016-03-07 09:30:57.254 3 COMMIT 
2016-03-07 09:30:57.254 3 CREATE TABLE Raw_V8_Prefix ( RouterIP VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL, SysUptime BIGINT, Secs BIGINT, Nsecs BIGINT, Flow_Sequence BIGINT NOT NULL, Engine_Type CHAR(1) NOT NULL, Engine_ID CHAR(1) NOT NULL, Flows BIGINT NOT NULL, dPkts BIGINT NOT NULL, dOctets BIGINT NOT NULL, aFirst BIGINT NOT NULL, aLast BIGINT NOT NULL, Src_Prefix VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL, Dst_Prefix VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL, Src_Mask INT NOT NULL, Dst_Mask INT NOT NULL, Src_As INT NOT NULL, Dst_As INT NOT NULL, Input INT NOT NULL, Output INT NOT NULL, Stamp VARCHAR(15) NULL ) 
2016-03-07 09:30:57.254 3 COMMIT 
2016-03-07 09:30:57.254 3 CREATE TABLE Raw_V9 ( RouterIP VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL, SysUptime BIGINT, Secs BIGINT, PackageSequence BIGINT NOT NULL, SourceID BIGINT NOT NULL, SrcAddr VARCHAR(15) NULL, DstAddr VARCHAR(15) NULL, NextHop VARCHAR(15) NULL, Input INT NULL, Output INT NULL, dPkts BIGINT, dOctets BIGINT, aFirst BIGINT, aLast BIGINT, SrcPort INT NULL, DstPort INT NULL, Tcp_Flags INT NULL, Prot INT NULL, TOS INT NULL, Src_As INT NULL, Dst_As INT NULL, Src_Mask INT NULL, Dst_Mask INT NULL, Stamp VARCHAR(15) NULL ) 
2016-03-07 09:30:57.254 3 COMMIT 
2016-03-07 09:30:57.254 3 CREATE TABLE OptionsTable ( RouterIP VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL, SysUptime BIGINT, Secs BIGINT, PackageSequence BIGINT NOT NULL, SourceID BIGINT NOT NULL, IsScope VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL, Stamp VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL, TemplateID INT NOT NULL, OptionType INT NOT NULL, OptionValue BIGINT NOT NULL ) 
2016-03-07 09:30:57.254 3 COMMIT 
2016-03-07 09:30:57.254 3 CREATE TABLE SrcAS ( StartDate DATE NOT NULL, StartTime TIME NOT NULL, EndDate DATE NOT NULL, EndTime TIME NOT NULL, RouterIP VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL, Flows BIGINT NOT NULL, Missed BIGINT NOT NULL, dPkts BIGINT NOT NULL, dOctets BIGINT NOT NULL, Src_As VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL, Stamp VARCHAR(15) NULL ) 
2016-03-07 09:30:57.254 3 COMMIT 
2016-03-07 09:30:57.254 3 CREATE TABLE DstAS ( StartDate DATE NOT NULL, StartTime TIME NOT NULL, EndDate DATE NOT NULL, EndTime TIME NOT NULL, RouterIP VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL, Flows BIGINT NOT NULL, Missed BIGINT NOT NULL, dPkts BIGINT NOT NULL, dOctets BIGINT NOT NULL, Dst_As VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL, Stamp VARCHAR(15) NULL ) 
2016-03-07 09:30:57.254 3 COMMIT 
2016-03-07 09:30:57.269 3 CREATE TABLE ASMatrix ( StartDate DATE NOT NULL, StartTime TIME NOT NULL, EndDate DATE NOT NULL, EndTime TIME NOT NULL, RouterIP VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL, Flows BIGINT NOT NULL, Missed BIGINT NOT NULL, dPkts BIGINT NOT NULL, dOctets BIGINT NOT NULL, Src_As VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL, Dst_As VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL, Stamp VARCHAR(15) NULL ) 
2016-03-07 09:30:57.269 3 COMMIT 
2016-03-07 09:30:57.269 3 CREATE TABLE SrcNode ( StartDate DATE NOT NULL, StartTime TIME NOT NULL, EndDate DATE NOT NULL, EndTime TIME NOT NULL, RouterIP VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL, Flows BIGINT NOT NULL, Missed BIGINT NOT NULL, dPkts BIGINT NOT NULL, dOctets BIGINT NOT NULL, SrcNode VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL, Stamp VARCHAR(15) NULL ) 
2016-03-07 09:30:57.269 3 COMMIT 
2016-03-07 09:30:57.269 3 CREATE TABLE DstNode ( StartDate DATE NOT NULL, StartTime TIME NOT NULL, EndDate DATE NOT NULL, EndTime TIME NOT NULL, RouterIP VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL, Flows BIGINT NOT NULL, Missed BIGINT NOT NULL, dPkts BIGINT NOT NULL, dOctets BIGINT NOT NULL, DstNode VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL, Stamp VARCHAR(15) NULL ) 
2016-03-07 09:30:57.269 3 COMMIT 
2016-03-07 09:30:57.269 3 CREATE TABLE HostMatrix ( StartDate DATE NOT NULL, StartTime TIME NOT NULL, EndDate DATE NOT NULL, EndTime TIME NOT NULL, RouterIP VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL, Flows BIGINT NOT NULL, Missed BIGINT NOT NULL, dPkts BIGINT NOT NULL, dOctets BIGINT NOT NULL, SrcNode VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL, DstNode VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL, Stamp VARCHAR(15) NULL ) 
2016-03-07 09:30:57.269 3 COMMIT 
2016-03-07 09:30:57.269 3 CREATE TABLE SrcInt ( StartDate DATE NOT NULL, StartTime TIME NOT NULL, EndDate DATE NOT NULL, EndTime TIME NOT NULL, RouterIP VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL, Flows BIGINT NOT NULL, Missed BIGINT NOT NULL, dPkts BIGINT NOT NULL, dOctets BIGINT NOT NULL, SrcInt INT NOT NULL, Stamp VARCHAR(15) NULL ) 
2016-03-07 09:30:57.269 3 COMMIT 
2016-03-07 09:30:57.269 3 CREATE TABLE DstInt ( StartDate DATE NOT NULL, StartTime TIME NOT NULL, EndDate DATE NOT NULL, EndTime TIME NOT NULL, RouterIP VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL, Flows BIGINT NOT NULL, Missed BIGINT NOT NULL, dPkts BIGINT NOT NULL, dOctets BIGINT NOT NULL, DstInt INT NOT NULL, Stamp VARCHAR(15) NULL ) 
2016-03-07 09:30:57.269 3 COMMIT 
2016-03-07 09:30:57.269 3 CREATE TABLE IntMatrix ( StartDate DATE NOT NULL, StartTime TIME NOT NULL, EndDate DATE NOT NULL, EndTime TIME NOT NULL, RouterIP VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL, Flows BIGINT NOT NULL, Missed BIGINT NOT NULL, dPkts BIGINT NOT NULL, dOctets BIGINT NOT NULL, SrcInt INT NOT NULL, DstInt INT NOT NULL, Stamp VARCHAR(15) NULL ) 
2016-03-07 09:30:57.269 3 COMMIT 
2016-03-07 09:30:57.269 3 CREATE TABLE SrcPrefix ( StartDate DATE NOT NULL, StartTime TIME NOT NULL, EndDate DATE NOT NULL, EndTime TIME NOT NULL, RouterIP VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL, Flows BIGINT NOT NULL, Missed BIGINT NOT NULL, dPkts BIGINT NOT NULL, dOctets BIGINT NOT NULL, SrcPrefix VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL, SrcMask INT NOT NULL, SrcAS INT NOT NULL, Input INT NOT NULL, Stamp VARCHAR(15) NULL ) 
2016-03-07 09:30:57.269 3 COMMIT 
2016-03-07 09:30:57.285 3 CREATE TABLE DstPrefix ( StartDate DATE NOT NULL, StartTime TIME NOT NULL, EndDate DATE NOT NULL, EndTime TIME NOT NULL, RouterIP VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL, Flows BIGINT NOT NULL, Missed BIGINT NOT NULL, dPkts BIGINT NOT NULL, dOctets BIGINT NOT NULL, DstPrefix VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL, DstMask INT NOT NULL, DstAS INT NOT NULL, Output INT NOT NULL, Stamp VARCHAR(15) NULL ) 
2016-03-07 09:30:57.285 3 COMMIT 
2016-03-07 09:30:57.285 3 CREATE TABLE PrefixMatrix ( StartDate DATE NOT NULL, StartTime TIME NOT NULL, EndDate DATE NOT NULL, EndTime TIME NOT NULL, RouterIP VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL, Flows BIGINT NOT NULL, Missed BIGINT NOT NULL, dPkts BIGINT NOT NULL, dOctets BIGINT NOT NULL, SrcPrefix VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL, SrcMask INT NOT NULL, SrcAS INT NOT NULL, Input INT NOT NULL, DstPrefix VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL, DstMask INT NOT NULL, DstAS INT NOT NULL, Output INT NOT NULL, Stamp VARCHAR(15) NULL ) 
2016-03-07 09:30:57.285 3 COMMIT 
2016-03-07 09:30:57.285 3 CREATE TABLE Protocol ( StartDate DATE NOT NULL, StartTime TIME NOT NULL, EndDate DATE NOT NULL, EndTime TIME NOT NULL, RouterIP VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL, Flows BIGINT NOT NULL, Missed BIGINT NOT NULL, dPkts BIGINT NOT NULL, dOctets BIGINT NOT NULL, Protocol VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL, Stamp VARCHAR(15) NULL ) 
2016-03-07 09:30:57.285 3 COMMIT 
2016-03-07 09:30:57.285 3 ROLLBACK 
2016-03-07 09:30:57.285 5 ROLLBACK 
2016-03-07 09:30:57.285 8 ROLLBACK 
2016-03-07 09:30:57.285 7 ROLLBACK 
2016-03-07 09:30:57.285 6 ROLLBACK 
2016-03-07 09:30:57.285 4 ROLLBACK 
2016-03-07 09:30:57.285 9 ROLLBACK 
2016-03-07 09:30:57.285 10 ROLLBACK 
2016-03-07 09:30:57.285 11 ROLLBACK 
2016-03-07 09:30:57.285 12 ROLLBACK 
2016-03-07 09:31:02.371 13 select * from IpSegments 
2016-03-07 09:31:02.371 13 COMMIT 
2016-03-07 09:32:02.026 14 INSERT INTO Raw_V9 ( RouterIP, SysUptime, Secs, PackageSequence, SourceID, SrcAddr, DstAddr, NextHop, Input, Output, dPkts, dOctets, aFirst, aLast, SrcPort, DstPort, Tcp_Flags, Prot, TOS, Src_As, Dst_As, Src_Mask, Dst_Mask, Stamp ) VALUES( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) ('192.168.10.23',888693100,1457339958,30207,0,'178.182.11.16','158.47.120.3','192.168.20.12',1,13,7,1981,888621984,888681988,1660,2405,16,17,0,0,0,24,24,'20160307093202')
2016-03-07 09:32:02.026 14 COMMIT 
2016-03-07 09:32:02.026 14 INSERT INTO Raw_V9 ( RouterIP, SysUptime, Secs, PackageSequence, SourceID, SrcAddr, DstAddr, NextHop, Input, Output, dPkts, dOctets, aFirst, aLast, SrcPort, DstPort, Tcp_Flags, Prot, TOS, Src_As, Dst_As, Src_Mask, Dst_Mask, Stamp ) VALUES( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) ('192.168.10.23',888693100,1457339958,30207,0,'178.182.11.4','192.168.11.4','192.168.11.4',1,13,2,110,888669256,888669260,49642,2404,24,6,0,0,0,24,24,'20160307093202')
2016-03-07 09:32:02.026 14 COMMIT 
2016-03-07 09:32:02.026 14 INSERT INTO Raw_V9 ( RouterIP, SysUptime, Secs, PackageSequence, SourceID, SrcAddr, DstAddr, NextHop, Input, Output, dPkts, dOctets, aFirst, aLast, SrcPort, DstPort, Tcp_Flags, Prot, TOS, Src_As, Dst_As, Src_Mask, Dst_Mask, Stamp ) VALUES( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) ('192.168.10.23',888693100,1457339958,30207,0,'192.168.11.4','178.182.11.4','178.182.11.4',13,1,1,58,888669260,888669260,2404,49642,24,6,0,0,0,24,24,'20160307093202')
2016-03-07 09:32:02.026 14 COMMIT 
2016-03-07 09:32:32.165 13 ROLLBACK 
2016-03-07 09:32:32.181 16 ROLLBACK 
2016-03-07 09:32:32.197 14 ROLLBACK 
2016-03-07 09:32:32.197 22 ROLLBACK 
2016-03-07 09:32:32.197 20 ROLLBACK 
2016-03-07 09:32:32.197 15 ROLLBACK 
2016-03-07 09:32:32.197 17 ROLLBACK 
2016-03-07 09:32:32.197 19 ROLLBACK 
2016-03-07 09:32:32.197 21 ROLLBACK 
2016-03-07 09:32:32.197 18 ROLLBACK
```

What could be the cause for this behaviour ?

Feel free to ask for more info as I'm new and I have surely omitted some important details

Comment: it's hard to say as we don't see app status.. are you able to sniff network traffic (like etheral) and coordinate actions?

Comment: yes, I was using Wireshark to check that the client was receiving the netflow flows

Answer (score 0):

The COMMIT and ROLLBACK logs entries are mostly from different connections.

Even when there is a ROLLBACK after a COMMIT on the same connection, it cannot roll back the already committed change. AFAIR, a ROLLBACK was also logged when a connection was closed.